# What logic can I use to resume an interrupted shell script?

Tags: bash, function, shell, menu

I have written a large script to run a series of tests. Each test is a function on its own and I call these functions serially to get the job done.

I now want to make provisions to resume script run from the last function where it was aborted (e.g. in case system hangs). The logic I am using now is to write progress status into a file and then check the file content to determine where to start the script and resume from there.

However, I can't continue using this logic because I want to introduce a menu into the script where I want to be able to choose from:

1) Run all tests from beginning to end
2) Run individual tests (brings up another menu with individual test options)
3) Resume from last abort

I have the written the code for the menu but still haven't figured out how to fit my existing logic with the case construct used in my menu system. I am unhappy with the current resume from last abort logic I am using presently, which is:

```
fn1()
{
  #do a bunch of things
  echo 1 > progress.log
  fn2
}

fn2()
{
STATUS=`cat progress.log`
case "$STATUS" in 
1)
  #do a bunch of things
  echo 2 > progress.log
  fn3
;;
*)
 fn3
;;
esac
}

..
..
# and more functions in the same style as fn2
..

# main call

if [ -f progress.log ]
 fn2
else
 fn1
fi
```

Any ideas for a cleaner way to do this resume logic while integrating it with the ability to run tests individually when required? Thanks.

Comment: this sounds like a good case to use Make to manage your tests. Make can store a file after a recipe completes. if that file exists, it will skip that recipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this.  Drop the logic in fn1..N that link them together, but still write the `progress.log` file in there, and then do this:

```
runtest()
{
    # run test X where X is 1..N
    case "$1" in
    1) fn1 ;;
    2) fn2 ;;
    3) fn3 ;;
    *) echo "Invalid test number $1" ;;
    esac
}

runtests()
{
    START="$1"; shift
    [ -z "$START"] && START=1 # default to test 1
    for i in $(seq "$START" 50); do # replace 50 with max test number
        runtest $i
    done
}

# from your menu, run from start:
runtests 1
# from menu, run from progress
runtests $(< progress.log)
# from menu, run test TESTNUM
runtest $TESTNUM
# or by name (this is dangerous if you don't trust the user):
eval "$TESTNAME"
```

EDIT: with this version, you can just replace fn1, fn2, etc with the test names, so that you still get a runtest N interface that you can use to tie it all together.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks for the input. However, I can't use this because the functions aren't named fn1 .. fnN. I just used them here as an example. I don't want to rename the functions either. I want the function names to make sense of the test being run.

Comment: Okay, let me edit my solution then, to use the case as suggested as an alternative in the runtest function.

Comment: I think you should not only set, but also use a **START** variable in `runtests`:) Actually i would recommend to get rid of it altogether and rewrite the set in `for` as something like `$(seq ${1:-1} 50)`

Comment: Good call, though I prefer using the variable to your other suggestion; it reads more clearly to me personally since I mostly program in other languages that don't have anything like bash's `${X:Y}` syntax.

Comment: @Walter Mundt Why did you use the shift command here? Was it really necessary?

Comment: Nope, not needed in this case, just habit.  If you had multiple args you could just keep repeating that line, and if you wanted to forward all but the first few to some command then having the ones you need shifted off the list is convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Bash supports "case cascade" aka fall through. Hence you can write/read progress into/from a file and the act accordingly via case cascade. For instance

```
function write_progress
{
    local step_name=$1
    echo "$(date '+%F %H:%M:%S') $step_name" >> "$PROGRESS_FILE"

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        error_out "failed to update progress"
    fi
}


function read_proress
{
    local step_name
    step_name=$(tail -1 "$PROGRESS_FILE" | cut -d' ' -f 3)

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        error_out "failed to read progress"
    fi
}

case $(read_proress) in
    step1) 
        echo do_sth_for_step1
        ;&
    step2)
        echo step2_thing
        ;&
    step3)
        echo step3_thing
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: This syntax doesn't work for bash 3.2, which is still the default bash in macOS.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you may use something like `eval fn$(cat status)`. In the end of each function you call `runnext` which derives the number of the current function, adds 1 and calls the resulting function through `eval`.